# Is there a way to hide node.js code

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, docker, amazon-ami, aws-marketplace

So as the deployment of our app we were thinking to deploy it in market place as a private ami.So we were thinking to  get the docker image of the app when some one spinning up the vm with our ami.But the thing is the user who spin up the ami is the admin of the vm so he has full access.So does he has access to our code base when he ssh in to the docekr image.Is there a way to restrict user to access the code

Comment: The only way to be sure no-one has access to your code is if that code never leaves your server.

Comment: @Amadan I dont think u got what am saying

Comment: I know what you're saying, and it's called "security by obscurity". No code is safe if you have access; it is only a matter of how badly they want it if they'll go through hoops to decompile/decrypt/deobfuscate whatever they have. As wizzwizz4 says, host it on your server if you want to be sure they can't get it; if you need to hand it over, either get resigned about it, or make sure you have very good lawyers to punish them if they do things you don't want (and you hear about it and have evidence and...)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. Let *them* use *your* AWS server and don't give their account SSH access to the code.

Seriously. There isn't a trick to this one. This is the only way you can do it, short of SELinux.

Comment: no mate we have to deploy this on promises.I was thinking a way to hide code from docker or compiling the node code to binary form

Comment: @AyeshmanthaPerera It's JavaScript. They could just decompile it... Actually, there is _one_ deployment option I can think of that might work...

Comment: No. Not even `unshare` can beat root.

Comment: Why would SELinux be different? If you have root or sudo privileges, you can still do whatever you want, no? For one thing, `sudo setenforce 0`... (If you meant SELinux inside Docker, it can't do that - AFAIK inside a container SE will always be disabled)